# Backbone GoogleMaps MarkerCollectionView collection and pagination

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js

I'm building a page which holds 2 different views. the first view is a list of locations and their information and the second view is a google map which shows markers of the locations which is displayed on the first view.

The problem at the moment that since the collection can be big and my page holds a pagination and displays 20 locations on each page, the second view shows the whole locations markers.

I would like to show in the second view which is a google map the markers depending on the page I'm on.

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have View number 2(The map),
Listen to a change in the collection that is shown in View number 1(The list).

In view 2, When the collection of places/markers change, you need to call the setMap, clear all the markers, then call collection.forEach, and place the marker on the map.